# Unity 2D - how to have enemy chasing a target avoid an object using raycast

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an enemy which is chasing a target. This works great, however there is a square object in the center of the map. If the target is on one side of the square and the enemy on the other, the enemy will get stuck on the object since it's moving in the direction of the target.

I have a raycast which does detect the object if it's within a certain range. The piece I am missing is how do I now make the enemy go around the object?

```
//check where the target is and set a straight line
Rigidbody2D targetRb = target.GetComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D)) as Rigidbody2D;
Vector2 targetPos = targetRb.position;
// rb is current game object rigid body
Vector2 toVec = targetPos - rb.position;

// ...
// ...
// At this point I have a RaycastHit2D object which is the hit on the object.
// Can I update toVec, or rb (current rigid body) to make the enemy avoid the object?
// ...
// ...

// Later I move the enemy towards the target with the following
 rb.velocity = new Vector2(toVec.normalized.x * moveSpeed, toVec.normalized.y * moveSpeed);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using A* or a bezier curve between two points would be a better approach, but my solution is to draw a ray between two points and if there is an obstacle between them, take a random point between the first point and the second one and draw two rays between the three new points, so if you have multiple obstacles it still can find a way (use the method for your path finding, the Gizmos method is for demonstration purposes):

```
[SerializeField] private Transform start;
[SerializeField] private Transform end;
[SerializeField] private List<Vector3> position;
[SerializeField] private LayerMask layerMask;
[SerializeField] private bool calculate;

private void OnValidate()
{
    if (!calculate) return;
    position = new List<Vector3>();
    calculate = false;
    position.Add(start.position);
    Calculate(start.position, end.position);
    position.Add(end.position);
}


private void Calculate(Vector3 p0, Vector3 p1)
{
    var direction = (p1 - p0).normalized;
    // hits obstacle
    if (Physics.Raycast(p0, direction, 1000, layerMask))
    {
        position.Remove(p1);
        var middle = (p0 + p1) / 2;
        middle.y += Random.Range(2, 5);
        position.Add(middle);
        Calculate(p0, middle);
        Calculate(middle, p1);
    }
}

private void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    Gizmos.DrawLine(start.position, end.position);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < position.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        Gizmos.DrawLine(position[i + 1], position[i]);
    }
}
```

and this is how it corrects the way:

[image: Good Output]

nevertheless, it can lead to infinity:

[image: Bad Output]